# How to combine for key value with while loop?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to console log `test` every time there is a match with the  object array and the JSON text key.

It will log each tag inside the object array, but the while loop isn't working as expect.

An working example: http://codepen.io/Caspert/pen/PZYjPV?editors=001

```
var text_buffer = raw_content.text;

var raw_content = {
    "text": "Test image 1 [image] Test image 2 [image] Test image 3 [image] Test image 4 [image]",
    "media": [{
        "image": {
            "src": "http://placehold.it/400x200",
            "caption": "This is a caption"
        }
    }, {
        "image": {
            "src": "images/gallery/sh0.png",
            "caption": "This is a caption"
        }
    }, {
        "image": {
            "src": "http://placehold.it/400x200",
            "caption": "This is a caption"
        }
    }, {
        "image": {
            "src": "images/gallery/sh0.png",
            "caption": "This is a caption"
        }
    }]
};

// Find multiple tags
var tags = {
    "image": '[image]',
    "gallery": '[gallery]'
};

for (var key in tags) {
    if (tags.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var tag = tags[key];
        console.log('tag = ', tag);

        while (text_buffer.indexOf(tag) !== -1) {
            console.log('test');
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: What is `text_buffer`?

Comment: what is  text_buffer?

Comment: This looks like a partial code... try to put together a working JsFiddle that demonstrates the problem so we can help you

Comment: My apologize. Update the question.

Comment: Also, the code here is messed up. You refer to `raw_content.text` before defining it. It will throw an exception... again- JsFiddle it or it didn't happen :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop will hang because `indexOf` will always be searching for the first instance of your `tag` variable, which will always be present. Best way round this is by specifying a start index to search from:

```
var startIndex = -1;

while ((startIndex = raw_content.text.indexOf(tag, startIndex + 1)) != -1) {
  console.log('test');
}
```

Look at this [example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bku3q0zL/3/).

Comment: I extended my answer a little bit, maybe you have some good advice to achieve it. And by the way, thanks for the solution. It is working correctly :)

Comment: @Caspert The update to your answer is a different question entirely. Please revert the question back to its original state, and start another question on SO using the 'Ask Question' button. It's a simple cut and paste job, but is extremely beneficial to both the community and to you, who will get more views on a question which has not yet been given answers.

Comment: My apologize, I was in doubt if I should create a new one, or extend this one. I will create a new post!

Comment: @Caspert No problem. The key to SO is the maintaining of the community, as well as the individual education of its members - so I felt obliged to point that out. I will take a look at your new question when you've posted it.

Comment: I understand it. The question was also not a good question, so I scrapped it. Thanks a lot for the solution!

Comment: @Caspert my pleasure :-)